# Why does the method getNodeSuccess work, but not getNodeFail?

Tags: c++, unordered-map, accessor, default-constructor

I am confused regarding the behavior of the following code: I don't understand why the `getNodeSuccess` method works, but the `getNodeFail` method fails to build. The only difference between those two methods is that one uses the `[]` operator for accessing the map, and the other one the `at` method. I thought that both these operations were returning a reference to the element in the map, and both should basically do the same thing. However, when I use the `[]` operator instead of the `at()`method, it tries to call the default constructor of the GraphNode class. Since the default constructor is private, the build fails.

For demonstration, I've made the default constructor of the `GraphNode` class private. If I change it to public, than it works.

Can somebody explain what's going on here? Why does one method trigger the default constructor, and not the other one?

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <exception>

template <class T>
struct GraphNode
{
    int id;
    T data;
    std::list<int> adj; // adjacency list

    GraphNode(const int id) 
    {
        this->id = id;
    }
private:
    GraphNode() {}
};

template<class T>
struct UndirectedGraph 
{
    std::unordered_map<int, GraphNode<T>> lookup;
    std::vector<GraphNode<T>> vertices;

    void addNode(const GraphNode<T> node) 
    {
        // if the id of the node already exists, than we cannot add it
        if (lookup.find(node.id) == lookup.end())
            lookup.insert(std::make_pair(node.id, node));
        else
            throw std::runtime_error("Trying to add a node that already exists.");
    }

    void addEdge(const int source, const int destination) 
    {
        getNodeSuccess(source).adj.push_back(destination);
        getNodeSuccess(destination).adj.push_back(source);

        getNodeFail(source).adj.push_back(destination);
        getNodeFail(destination).adj.push_back(source);
    }

    GraphNode<T>& getNodeSuccess(const int id)
    {
        if (lookup.find(id) == lookup.end())
            throw std::runtime_error("Trying to retrieve a node that doesn't exist");

        return lookup.at(id);
    }

    GraphNode<T>& getNodeFail(const int id)
    {
        if (lookup.find(id) == lookup.end())
            throw std::runtime_error("Trying to retrieve a node that doesn't exist");

        return lookup[id];
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    UndirectedGraph<int> graph;

    graph.addNode(GraphNode<int>(1));
    graph.addNode(GraphNode<int>(3));
    graph.addEdge(1, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`operator[]` will either `return` a reference to the value with that key, or create one using the default constructor, insert it, and `return` a reference to the newly constructed value.  Thus, your problem is that `operator[]` must be able to at least call the default constructor, *even if you know the key will always be present*.

If you just want to lookup whether something is in your `unordered_map`, your use of `find` is already close.

```
GraphNode<T>& getNodeFail(const int id)
{
    auto it = lookup.find(id);
    if (it == lookup.end())
        throw std::runtime_error("Trying to retrieve a node that doesn't exist");
    return it->second;
}
```

That will save you an extra lookup as well, since you already did the work once with `find`.